# Audio waveform matching

Tags: python, wav, waveform

[image]

[image]

I am matching two waveform of 400 ms. I am using correlate to check the shift.

```
cc = correlate(b1,b2,mode="same")
n=len(cc)
cc=2*cc/n
dur=n*dt1/2;
d=linspace( -dur, dur, n )
idx = argmax(cc)
```

I am getting the shift between 2 waveform. But how to get the actual match position of two waveform?

Comment: The shift you get is the shift you need to move b1 in order it to give the maximum coorelation with b2.

Comment: I have attached the images. Shift is 0.015 ms between the two. I can shift 0.015 ms but actual matching starts from 0.26 ms

Answer (score 0):

you probably want `mode = "full"` and need to do some more math to pick the correlation peak and adjust for the sequence length padding

hopefully this example will help show the issues:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [math.sin(i* math.pi/10) for i in range(300)]
b = [math.cos(i*math.pi/10) for i in range(300)]
plt.plot(a, 'red')
plt.plot(b, 'green')

axb= np.correlate(a,b, mode="full")/100.0
x = range(len(axb))
plt.plot(x, axb)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried mode=full. i have no issues picking the correlation peak and getting he lag between the two signals. How to find the sequence length padding? How to remove the unwanted signal in the beginning?

Comment: It looks like `mode='same'` wraps the input sequences, which mode to use  depends on your problem, the experimental setup, expected signal properties.  Again depending on everything, multiple peaks in the correlation can have significance or not.  Trying examples like my plot may help understanding the different modes, their offset conventions, if not obvious from reading the doc.